# Simple explanation needed about EU's decisional and normative supranationalism

Tags: european-union, nationalism

Please explain like I'm five:  I get what's "supranationalism", but why didn't Craig define **decisional supranationalism** and **normative supranationalism**?  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supranational_union#Categorising_European_supranationalism) was too gruff to help!

---

[*European Union Governance and Policy Making: A Canadian Perspective*. 2018](https://utorontopress.com/ca/european-union-governance-and-policy-making-2). p. 397 of 424.

> **Supranational / supranationalism:** In EU decision-making, processes that are controlled by institutions that represent the EU as a whole, rather than the member states, and are designed to express the common European interest.

Craig, P and De Burca, G. [*EU Law* 6 ed. 2015](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/eu-law-9780198714927?cc=ca&lang=en&). All emboldenings are mine.

p. 147

> These developments contributed to the Euro-sclerosis that beset the Community during much
>   of the 1970s, which had implications for the ECJ’s role. This story has been told most fully in the
>   important work of Joseph Weiler.<sup>143</sup> He explains how impediments to attainment of Community
>   objectives through the political process led to the growing importance of **normative supranationalism**.
>   The doctrines of direct effect, the supremacy of Community law, and pre-emption were central
>   in this respect, enabling the Court to develop EC law, notwithstanding the difficulties in securing
>   enactment through the legislative process.<sup>1443</sup>

p. 192

> The Court’s concern was to ensure that the EU’s aims were not ignored either by reluctant Member
>   States or by sluggish EU institutions, during the years of so-called legislative sclerosis which followed
>   the Luxembourg Accords.<sup>26</sup> This story has been told most fully by Weiler, who has explained how
>   impediments to attainment of Community objectives through the political process, **decisional supranationalism**,
>   led to the growing importance of **normative supranationalism**.<sup>27</sup> The doctrines of direct
>   effect and the supremacy of Community law were central in this respect, enabling the ECJ to develop
>   EU law, notwithstanding the difficulties in securing enactment through the legislative process. If a
>   national court was unsure of the exact meaning of the relevant provision, the ECJ was more than willing
>   to clarify its scope through the preliminary ruling procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there's something specific in that Weiler reference (143), these words appear to have their usual meaning.

*Normative* means "setting the norm" (how things should be done).

*Decisional*  means "as decided" (how things are going to be done).

That is to say, **normative supranationalism** means that supranationalism is viewed as the way things should be, while **decisional supranationalism** means that supranationalism is a solution that politicians came up with. Or even simpler. normative supranationalism is a goal, while decisional supranationalism is a tool.